# F# - Converting nested for-loops to a functional style

Tags: f#, functional-programming

I'm trying to convert my nested for-loops to a more functional style.

I've been messing around with pipelining, sequences, and arrays, but to no avail.

Here's what I have:

```
let allCarrierCodes = new List<string>()    
for result in getAllCarrierCodesResults do
        for carrierCode in result do
            allCarrierCodes.Add(carrierCode.ToString())
```

- `getAllCarrierCodesResults` is a seq of type "obj list"

What's a nice functional way to re-write the nested loops?

Thanks.

Comment: Apart from re-writing the nested loop, consider switching from the "normal" List (`System.Collections.Generic.List`) to F# lists, which are immutable. It will give you access to all the F# goodies like pattern matching. With Lee's answer below, that would be `let allCodes = getAllCarriesCodes |> Seq.concat |> Seq.map string |> List.ofSeq`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `Seq.collect`:

```
let allCodes = Seq.collect id getAllCarrierCodesResults 
               |> Seq.map string)
```

or

```
let allCodes = Seq.collect (Seq.map string) getAllCarrierCodesResults
```

you can then convert the resulting `seq<string>` into the concrete collection you want.

Comment: Rather than writing `Seq.collect id`, I'd use `Seq.concat`.

Comment: Also, you can make use of the new feature in F# 4, where [constructors can be used as first-class functions](https://github.com/fsharp/FSharpLangDesign/blob/master/FSharp-4.0/ClassNamesAsFunctionsDesignAndSpec.md). With that, you can write `let allCodes = getAllCarriesCodes |> Seq.concat |> Seq.map string |> List` For the use of List, see my comment above.

Answer (score 8):

Lee's answer is better than this, but I just wanted to mention that you can totally just put those nested loops inside a list comprehension, and voila:

```
let allCarrierCodes =
  [for result in getAllCarrierCodesResults do
     for carrierCode in result do
       yield carrierCode.ToString()]
```

Looks kind of imperative-ish, but is really functional.

Also, you should use `string carrierCode` instead of `carrierCode.ToString()`. Protects you from NRE and looks more functional for added bonus :-)

Comment: if you advice about not using `.ToString()`, why do you use it in your answer?

Comment: In order to keep it as close as possible to the OP's code.